# Center container AND use negative margin

Tags: html, css

I am styling figures.

I want to make it so that when the image is smaller than the text column, the figure shrinks to its size and centers, for that I'm using:

```css
div {
  width: 20em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
figure {
  display: table;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  padding: 2rem 2rem;
  background-color: #eee;
}
figure img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div><figure>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="100x100 placeholder">
 </figure>
<figure>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/400x100" alt="400x100 placeholder">
</figure></div>
```

The problem is that I want the figure to bleed outside the column when the image is the size of the column. For that I'd normally use:

```css
div {
  width: 20em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
figure {
  display: table;
  margin: 1rem -2rem;
  padding: 2rem 2rem;
  background-color: #eee;
}
figure img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div><figure>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="100x100 placeholder">
 </figure>
<figure>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/400x100" alt="400x100 placeholder">
</figure></div>
```

but that solution removes the `margin: auto;` centering

I'd appreciate CSS only solutions, but js and jquery will do if there's no other way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `figure` as an `inline-table` and apply `text-align:center` to the parent.

```css
body {
  background: lightgreen;
}
div {
  width: 20em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  text-align: center;
}
figure {
  display: inline-table;
  margin: 1rem -2rem;
  padding: 2rem 2rem;
  background-color: #eee;
}
figure img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="100x100 placeholder">
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/400x100" alt="400x100 placeholder">
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that make all siblings and nephews(?) of the figure use centered text? is there a way to make it non-inheritable?

Comment: No, you'd have to override it for any children etc but should be a simple enough CSS selector - https://jsfiddle.net/mhag64uy/

Comment: Dumb me, I was thinking I'd have to overwrite it in every single child...